# Copy char array to another char array without memory leak

Tags: c, arrays, memory

I have a function that dynamic memory allocation to char array:

```
static char **alsa_get_element(const char *card)
{
    snd_mixer_elem_t *elem;
    char **array1;
    int n = 0;

    elem = snd_mixer_first_elem(handle);

    while (elem != NULL)
    {
        if (snd_mixer_selem_has_playback_volume(elem) {
            char **tmp;

            tmp = (char **) realloc(array1, sizeof(char *) * (n + 1));
            if (tmp == NULL)
                break;

            array1 = tmp;
            array1[n++] = strdup(snd_mixer_selem_get_name(elem));
        }

        elem = snd_mixer_elem_next(elem);
    }

    if (array1 == (char **) 0)
        return NULL;

    array1 = (char **) realloc(array1, sizeof(char *) * (n + 1));
    array1[n] = NULL;

    return array1;
}
```

I want to move returned array from previous function to another array without resource leak.

```
int mixer_get_element(const char *card, char ***array2)
{
    int result = 0;
    char **array1 = NULL;

    array1 = alsa_get_element(card);
    if (array1 != NULL) {
        *array2 = array1 /* ?????????????? */
        result = 1;
    }

    return result;
}
```

How to copy the value of array1 to array2 ? Can I just do this:

```
*array2 = array1?
```

Regards

Comment: When is array1 freed?

Comment: `char **array2` --> `char ***array2` then `*array2 = array1;` also --> `char **array1 = NULL;`

Comment: In function `alsa_get_element`, you are calling `realloc(array1...)` without first initializing `array1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not stripped down to code to a MVCE, so I could not test if there are any other problems. But as `array1` has been allocated from the heap (via malloc/realloc), you can 
safely pass its address to any other function or return it.

Because when you write `*array2 = array1` you just copy the address of the array of pointers `array1` to the address pointed by `array2`.

The only rule is that you should free it somewhere in the caller of `mixer_get_element`.

And I'm unsure if it is needed or not, but I strongly advise you to initialize your pointers to NULL in `alsa_get_element` :

```
snd_mixer_elem_t *elem =  NULL;
char **array1 = NULL;
```

They are created in the stack, and optimized versions may not initialize those values to NULL.